# How can I determine the rule TXs are sorted in a block?

Tags: transactions, mining

Let's say I have a list of TXs in a block

https://etherscan.io/txs?block=17251778

What is the logic TXs are sorted?

I have read some posts but not sure if those are relevant to PoS and some latest upgrades/EIPs